# JavaFX 8: How to be able to re-size window (stage) but keep inner elements at their positions?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a project that has a 2 text areas and few buttons. The root pane is a AnchorPane. when resizing the window to smaller window, all the elements start overlap. What methods can fix this? (IGNORE THE NAME OF MY anchorpane, i got lazy)

```
    AnchorPane borderpane = new AnchorPane ();

    TextArea user_list = new TextArea();
    user_list.setPrefSize(150, 400);
    TextArea messages = new TextArea();
    messages.setPrefSize(350, 400);
    TextField typebox = new TextField();
    typebox.setPrefSize(425, 100);

    // put a shape over a text, over a shape
    StackPane send_container = new StackPane();

    Rectangle send_box = new Rectangle(75, 25);
    Label send_text = new Label("Send");

    send_container.getChildren().add(send_box);
    send_container.getChildren().add(send_text);

    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(messages, 25.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(messages, 10.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(user_list, 25.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(user_list, 10.0);

    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(typebox, 25.0); 
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(typebox, 25.0); 
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(send_container, 25.0); 
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(send_container, 25.0); 
    borderpane.getChildren().addAll(messages, user_list, typebox,send_container );


    Scene scene = new Scene(borderpane, 600, 600);
    primaryStage.setMaxHeight(600);
    primaryStage.setMaxWidth(600);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
    primaryStage.setTitle("Welcome");
    scene.getStylesheets().add(LoginWindow.class.getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Use a layout other than AnchorPane.  It is impossible to tell you exactly which layout will meet your needs, without seeing your current code and/or window.  [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) suits most needs.

Comment: @VGR ill post the code soon If i have to. Is this type of behavior common for AnchorPanes? Bascially, I want text are of size x on left side, text area of size y on right, text area on bottom expanding accross the two top text areas, and a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hard-coding the locations and sizes of your controls.  This means the controls cannot respond to changes in the size of their parent nodes.

Usually, you should not specify any heights or widths.  Controls all have default preferred sizes, and all layouts respect those.  Layouts also decide how child nodes will be resized in response to the user's resizing of a window.

Often, the layout of a window needs to be broken down into sub-layouts.  In your case, you want one section that always resizes to fill the window (the user list and message section), with another section at the bottom (the typebox and Send button).  A BorderPane is the ideal choice, since its center node always fills it.  So the center of this main BorderPane would contain the user list and message area, while the bottom of this BorderPane would contain the typebox and the Send button.

You probably want the user to be able to horizontally resize both the user list and the messages, so I'd put them in a SplitPane, and make that SpiltPane the center of the main BorderPane.

You probably want the typebox and Send button to be in a separate child BorderPane, with the typebox as the center node, since you want the typebox to stretch and shrink, horizontally, when the user resizes the window.

So, to summarize:

- user list and message area in a SplitPane
- typebox and Send button in a BorderPane
- parent BorderPane with user list/message section in the center, typebox/Send section on the bottom

The code for this is actually pretty short:

```
ListView user_list = new ListView();

TextArea messages = new TextArea();
messages.setPrefRowCount(12);
messages.setPrefColumnCount(30);

TextField typebox = new TextField();
typebox.setPrefColumnCount(30);

Button send_text = new Button("Send");
send_text.disableProperty().bind(
    typebox.lengthProperty().lessThan(1));

SplitPane top = new SplitPane(user_list, messages);
top.setDividerPosition(0, 1/3.0);

BorderPane bottom = new BorderPane();
bottom.setCenter(typebox);
bottom.setRight(send_text);
BorderPane.setMargin(typebox, new Insets(0, 12, 0, 0));

BorderPane main = new BorderPane();
main.setCenter(top);
main.setBottom(bottom);
BorderPane.setMargin(bottom, new Insets(12));

Scene scene = new Scene(main);

primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
primaryStage.setTitle("Welcome");
scene.getStylesheets().add(LoginWindow.class.getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());
primaryStage.show();
```

Notice that there are no hard-coded dimensions or coordinates (except the margins defined by the Insets objects).  Every control has a preferred size based on its properties, such as a TextField's preferred column count.

The workings of the various layouts are well documented.  I suggest reading about them in the [javafx.scene.layout package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html).

(I'm guessing the user list should be a ListView, not a TextArea, since typical chat programs allow selection of one or more users.  And I suspect your black Rectangle and send_text Label were intended to represent a disabled Button.)

Comment: this is a great solution. I wanted to ask, with this and some other things I been working with, as I shrink the window, scroll bars appear only on the message list and when i increase the size, no scroll bars appear. why is that? to recap, only scroll bars show on messages and when window is basically smallest it can be, as I increase size again, scroll bars don't appear, they only do when decreasing the size

Comment: I get that too.  TextArea scrollbar appearance seems to be buggy.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762491/javafx-textarea-unwanted-scrollbars-when-resizing.

Comment: atleast Im not the only one, let me ask this, is there anyway to disable moving the divider? It seems I can move it as I please but that is not what I am looking for :)

Comment: Certainly.  You can replace the SplitPane with a BorderPane.  Or, you could bind the user list's maxWidth property to its prefWidth property, to prevent the divider from allowing it to grow past its preferred size.

Comment: Ok I think I got what I needed. I used a Borderpane but I had a prefwidth for the user_list and not everything is the right size by default and resizes, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a pane other than a Anchor Pane. It's for absolute positioning. Try a stack pane or simple VBox.